# String offset in constructor (C++)

Tags: c++

Anyone to give me some advice how to get this? Thank you for any advice.

I am able to get this:

```
l1 [start]
l2 [start]
l3 [start]
l3 [end]
l4 [start]
l4 [end]
l2 [end]
l1 [end]
```

But I need this:

```
l1 [start]
  l2 [start]
    l3 [start]
    l3 [end]
  l4 [start]
  l4 [end]
  l2 [end]
l1 [end]
```

tasks.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Logger {
    std::ostream& a;
    std::string b;
    std::string strOffset;

public:
    Logger(std::ostream& a, std::string b);

    ~Logger();

    Logger sublogger(std::string sub);

};
```

tasks.cpp

```
#include "tasks.h"

Logger::Logger(std::ostream& a, std::string b) : a(a), b(b) {
    a << strOffset << b << " [start]" << std::endl;
}

Logger::~Logger() {
    a << b << " [end]" << std::endl;
}

Logger Logger::sublogger(std::string sub) {

    return Logger(a, sub);
};
```

This is how test case looks like:

```
TEST_CASE("Create subloggers") {
        std::stringstream ss;
        {
            Logger logger(ss, "l1");
            {
                auto logger2 = logger.sublogger("l2");

                {
                    auto logger3 = logger2.sublogger("l3");
                }

                auto logger4 = logger.sublogger("l4");
            }
        }
        std::string testString = ss.str();

        REQUIRE(ss.str() == R"(l1 [start]
  l2 [start]
    l3 [start]
    l3 [end]
  l4 [start]
  l4 [end]
  l2 [end]
l1 [end]
)");
```

[Live test](https://godbolt.org/z/bnqhTv9c1)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't output anything because it is never used. Please include an actual [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
class Logger {
    std::ostream& out;
    const std::string name;
    const std::string prefix;

public:
    Logger(std::ostream& stream, std::string name);
    ~Logger();
    Logger sublogger(std::string sub);

private:
    Logger(std::ostream& stream, std::string name, std::string prefix);

    Logger(const Logger&) = default;
    Logger(Logger&&) = default;
    Logger& operator=(const Logger&) = delete;
    Logger& operator=(Logger&&) = delete;
};

Logger::Logger(std::ostream& stream, std::string name, std::string prefix)
    : out(stream)
    , name(name)
    , prefix(prefix)
{
    out << prefix << name << " [start]" << std::endl;
}

Logger::Logger(std::ostream& stream, std::string name)
    : Logger(stream, name, {})
{
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
    out << prefix << name << " [end]" << std::endl;
}

Logger Logger::sublogger(std::string sub)
{
    return Logger(out, sub, prefix + "  ");
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K9f1Mzrvf

[string_view version](https://godbolt.org/z/5jqY5Y35h)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a RAAI Logger is, so it might not be it, but it works for your test case:

tasks.cpp

```cpp
#include "tasks.h"

Logger::Logger(std::ostream& a, std::string b) : a(a), b(b), offset(0) {
    a << b << " [start]" << std::endl;
}

Logger::Logger(std::ostream& a, std::string b, int offset) : a(a), b(b), offset(offset) {
    printOffset();

    a << b << " [start]" << std::endl;
}

Logger::~Logger() {
    printOffset();

    a << b << " [end]" << std::endl;
}

void Logger::printOffset() {
    for(int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
        a << "  ";
    }
}

Logger Logger::sublogger(std::string sub) {
    return Logger(a, sub, offset + 1);
};
```

tasks.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Logger {
    std::ostream& a;
    std::string b;
    int offset;

    void printOffset();

public:
    Logger(std::ostream& a, std::string b);
    Logger(std::ostream& a, std::string b, int offset);

    ~Logger();

    Logger sublogger(std::string sub);

};
```

Comment: RAII - [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).